# Is my Aggregation and Composition correct?

Tags: c#, uml, class-diagram

Is my aggregation relationship of my class (between ArrayCoordinate and Tile) is correct (especially the arrow direction)? If not, could you please provide a quick explanation on it?

Note : I've read some article on this subject, and I feel can't fully understand this matter. Thanks in advance.

[image: My class diagram]

[image]

[image]

EDIT :
Short description about the diagram :
Those are my class from my tile based strategy game. The Tile Class represents each tile on my "game board" to store objects a tile can contains of (e.g. character, tree, etc). And the ArrayCoordinate represents the indexing of a tile, for iteration purposes (similar to C# Point class).

EDIT 2 :
On Tile and ArrayCoordinate, the brief relationship explanation is : Every Tile has an ArrayCoordinate, and there is no tile without ArrayCoordinate. And every Tile always have at least 1 TileObject which also have ArrayCoordinate, to access it's location directly without accessing the Tile first. (Sorry if my explanation is confusing, please feel free to ask

Comment: No one can really answer that question without knowing how do you use both tile and array coordinate. Or what you pretend to do with them.

Comment: I have edited my post to put a description in. Please take a second look. Thanks for your post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `UML` is correct as long as we know it's interpretation (because we may not follow the standards for `UML`).

About your question:

> Is my aggregation relationship of my class (between `ArrayCoordinate`
>   and Tile) is correct (especially the arrow direction)?

Even that I know that your `UML` was designed on visual studio I don't really know the designing details of it and I'll be answering for general `UML` diagrams.

The answer depends on how do you interpret your own `UML`. Most of the times, when there is a relationship of 1-n between class A and class B, there is a arrow coming from class A pointing to class B, it may optionally have a * near class B (indicating that there is many of those B) and may also include a name in the arrow that indicates the name of the field that supports that aggregation. If the name is indicated in the arrow normally you can remove it from the `UML` fields so you don't have redundant information (replication). However your `UML` doesn't either have a name on the arrow nor it have a field that may indicate that relationship actually exists.

Secondly, and according to my reasoning, the `UML` representation of the aggregation between `TileObject` and `Tile` is in the wrong direction OR it is missing and actually exists but the `UML` as it is doesn't provide that information (expanding your `TileObject` class would help).

EDIT: About your new TileObject `UML` I would say that there was missing a field that supports the relationship with `Tile` **however** it seems that visual studio represents a 1-n relationship with a filled rhombus and doesn't include the fields that supports that relationship. 
Also it seems that sometimes visual studio represents a 1-1 relationship and other times it doesn't; in your example it represents a relationship between `Tile` and `BattleManager` with an unfilled rhombus however it doesn't do that between `TileObject` and `ArrayCordinate`. And if this is true then I am wondering why is there a n-n relationship between `Tile` and `TileObject`. (should it be a 1-n relationship instead?)

As I mentioned I am not really familiar with visual studio `UML` designer but I would try to keep the `UML` designing consistent (if possible). The only times that you want to skip consistency is to try to compact your designing.

About your second edit: I think you really **should avoid to short the relationship between classes**. By doing that you create an additional dependency and you have to know what is the purpose of that new field (which doesn't have a functional purpose but either a efficiency one). Finally most of times the benefits of doing that doesn't really worth.

Finally and answering your question: Your relationship between `ArrayCordinate` and `Tile` is fine because you stated the following:

> `ArrayCoordinate` represents the indexing of a tile, for iteration

That means that **must** exist a relationship of 1-n between  `ArrayCoordinate` and `Tile`.

Comment: 1. I've added TileObject, I hope you can expand your explanation

2. On Tile and ArrayCoordinate, the sentenced relationship is : Every Tile has an ArrayCoordinate, and there is no tile without ArrayCoordinate.

Comment: For further explanation, please look at "EDIT 2" section.

Comment: Thank you. One thing still bugging me, I guess that I have added field to represent the relation. And it is the ArrayCoordinate on both Tile and TileObject, TileObject[] on Tile. And  since it's an unidirectional, then there is no relationship Field in ArrayCoordinate and TileObject. Is that what u meant?

Comment: Have ArrayCordinate on Tile only (avoiding shortening the relationship). All relations have a direction so I don't really know what you meant on your second statement.

Comment: Alright then. The second statement is for your "I would say that there was missing a field that supports the relationship with Tile". I mean, I am intentionally not including Tile field on TileObject, since it's not bidirectional.

Comment: If that is your rule that is ok for me. But as I stated that do no follow the standards for UML.